# Is it possible to copy my accounts and put them on the computer version on Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Recently, I have been wanting to download the PC version of Skyrim. I was wondering, "Since I have two Orcs around level 36, and two other people and I don't want to restart all over again, is there a way to migrate or take my accounts and put them on the PC version?". So...now I am here, asking this question.

Comment: Were you playing on a console previously?  If so, which one?  It probably makes a difference to the answer.

Comment: I believe that Steam does have an option at the login screen to link your account with Playstation Network. Maybe if you contact Steam support about this question, they could tell you if something like that would be possible?